# I don't know if I download ffmpeg correctly

Tags: laravel

This is my first time using ffmpeg. I don't know if downloaded ffmpeg correctly or if i'm doing it wrong. I downloaded it from here https://github.com/pascalbaljetmedia/laravel-ffmpeg

I did this

```
$this->validate($request,array(
        'Company'=>'required',
        'video' => 'required|mimes:mp4,flv,wmv,avi,mov,qt|max:110000',
));

$user_id=Auth::user()->id;
$pro=User::find($user_id);
$pro->company_name=$request->Company;           

if($request->video) {
    $vid = $request->file('video');
    $filename = uniqid().$vid->getClientOriginalName();
    $vid = $request->file('video');
    //$filename = uniqid().$vid->getClientOriginalName();
    //$path = $vid->storeAs('introvideo', $filename);

    $t = Storage::disk('s3')->put($filename, file_get_contents($vid), 'public');
    $imageName = Storage::disk('s3')->url($filename);

   //ffmpeg binaries

    $ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create(array(
        'ffmpeg.binaries'  => "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\blog\public\ffmpeg-20181004-03123e4-win64-static\ffmpeg-20181004-03123e4-win64-static\bin\ffmpeg.exe",
        'ffprobe.binaries' => "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\blog\public\ffmpeg-20181004-03123e4-win64-static\ffmpeg-20181004-03123e4-win64-static\bin\ffprobe.exe"
    ));

    //$vid->move($location);
    $v=FFMpeg::fromDisk('s3')->open($imageName)->export()->toDisk('s3')->inFormat(new \FFMpeg\Format\Audio\Aac)->save($imageName.'mp4');

    $pro->video = $v;
```

then I get error message saying "Unable to load FFProbe" like I don't know whats going on. Can someone kindly help me please because I have no clue whats going on

Comment: That's just the php bridge. Do you have the actual `ffmpeg` binary installed? Try to run the command in the commandline of whatever platform you use.

Comment: @msg  Thank you for responding. I actually download it on my computer. I have the binaries and i saved them on my laravel public folder. and its still telling me "unable to upload ffprobe"? Whats wrong? I'm going to edit my code so you can see what i did for the binaries

Comment: @msg i edited it, do you see i?

Comment: I **think** your config is incorrect, since you say you have the binaries in your laravel folder. Try setting the full filesystem path to them i.e. `/var/www/html...`. See [here](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg#ffmpeg)

Comment: @msg I got nothing. This is really frustrating because I have been trying to solve this all day. I'm trying to use ffmpeg for my project to compress videos.

Comment: Since I'm pasting code I created an answer to ease the formatting. Did you try changing the path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So according to your code:

```
$ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create(array(
    'ffmpeg.binaries'  => '/ffmpeg',
    'ffprobe.binaries' => '/ffprobe'
));
```

`ffmpeg` binaries should be installed in `/`, but in your comments you state that "i saved them on my laravel public folder". Set the `binaries` parameter to the full path where they are.

Comment: I change the path and it still saying the same thing.I edited the code take a look

Comment: @Supercoder54551 It went over my head just until now. You seem to have two `FFMpeg` namespaces, the php and the laravel one. According to [this code](https://github.com/pascalbaljetmedia/laravel-ffmpeg/blob/8310f4be71611230abc92388368173205fe6415c/src/FFMpeg.php) laravel-ffmpeg will instantiate php-ffmpeg using its own configuration system, it's not using the `$ffmpeg` instance that you are creating manually.

Comment: Oh so what do I do now?

Comment: @Supercoder54551 you can configure it using [env files](https://github.com/pascalbaljetmedia/laravel-ffmpeg/blob/master/config/laravel-ffmpeg.php) if you are using them or the laravel config system. If all else fails, go over the [installation process](https://github.com/pascalbaljetmedia/laravel-ffmpeg#installation) once again.

Comment: okay I think i got it i am no longer getting that error message. Thank you for  so much for your help!!!!!

Comment: @Supercoder54551 glad you got it working. would you mind updating how did you do it ?